# T-SQL/SMSS - Highest Value in Date-Range by Location

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ranking, dense-rank

I am trying to find out the highest-grossing day per location (date and gross sales amount) in my dataset. I understand that Rank ordering may help here, but im a little stuck on how to go about that. Here is the script so far:

```
SELECT 
    DateKey,
    SUM(GrossSales),
    LocationKey    
FROM 
    dataset
GROUP BY
    DateKey, LocationKey
ORDER BY
    DateKey, LocationKey
```

I also tried this script too below, but it only returns the highest grossing day of all locations, not by each and every location:

```
SELECT 
    DateKey,
    LocationKey,
    SUM(GrossSales)
FROM 
    dataset
GROUP BY 
    DateKey, LocationKey
HAVING 
    SUM(GrossSales) = (SELECT MAX(GrossSales) 
                       FROM 
                           (SELECT SUM(GrossSales) AS GrossSales 
                            FROM dataset 
                            GROUP BY Datekey, LocationKey) a )
```

This is how is how I would like it to look like, as an example:

[image]

Is there an easy work around here, that I just cant see?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to perform the initial `GROUP BY` calculation in a subquery and include a ROW_NUMBER() or RANK() window function to assign sequence numbers. The outer query can then filter for sequence = 1.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    DateKey,
    GrossSales,
    LocationKey
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DateKey,
        SUM(GrossSales) AS GrossSales,
        LocationKey,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LocationKey ORDER BY SUM(GrossSales) DESC) AS RN
    FROM 
        dataset
    GROUP BY
        DateKey, LocationKey
) A
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY
    LocationKey
```

Replacing ROW_NUMBER() with RANK() would include all tied values.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ig6OI0pB) for a demo.

Comment: Thankyou T N. After reading your script I was so close to getting this right before I asked. But I fumbled at the ROW_NUMBER bit. It works great, and I've saved this for future use. I appreciate the time you have put in to help new people such as myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to T N's answer above...  Full test script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblTable1;
CREATE TABLE #tblTable1(DateKey date, LocationKey int, GrossSales decimal(28,2));

INSERT INTO #tblTable1(DateKey,LocationKey,GrossSales)
VALUES('2022-12-23', 1, 184611.714)
    ,('2021-12-27', 2, 150715.34)
    ,('2020-12-26', 3, 145581.95)
    ,('2018-12-26', 4, 132299.35)
    ,('2019-12-23', 5, 132241.59)
    ,('2017-12-26', 6, 131782.52)
    ,('2022-12-17', 7, 129764.68)
    ,('2022-12-29', 7, 9999999.68) --Added
    ,('2021-12-23', 8, 129029.79)
    ,('2022-12-21', 9, 126959.52)
    ,('2019-12-26', 10, 124160.79);

WITH cte_Stuff(LocationKey, DateKey, GrossSales, RowId)
AS (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT LocationKey, DateKey, GrossSales, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY LocationKey ORDER BY LocationKey, GrossSales DESC) AS RowId --TOP 100 PERCENTS is Lazy Mans way of trying to enfore sort order within the CTE
    FROM #tblTable1 t1
    ORDER BY LocationKey, GrossSales DESC
    )
SELECT LocationKey, DateKey, GrossSales
FROM cte_Stuff
WHERE RowId = 1
```

Comment: A quick note on `ORDER BY` in the CTE: Although the data coming out of that CTE may appear sorted, SQL semantics do not guarantee that the order is preserved in the final query results. In simple small cases, you very often see order preserved due to a correspondingly simple linear execution plan. However, for more complex queries where the database engine may resort to hash tables, parallel execution, or other non-linear execution plans, you may find that the order changes to something other than was expected. (The same applies to subqueries, and even tables ordered by the Primary Key.)